# How to call a custom listener upon ESC key instead of default shell listener?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, listener, rcp

I have a class that extends `ColumnViewerToolTipSupport`. This class overrides `createViewerToolTipContentArea()` and provides custom content for the tooltip.

When an ESC key is hit while the tooltip is open, the `shell.close()` method is called. Even when I have a key listener added to the tooltip shell, `shell.close()` itself is called.

Code for listener below:

```
   @Override
    protected Composite createViewerToolTipContentArea(Event event, ViewerCell cell, final Composite shell) {

        Display.getDefault().getActiveShell().addListener(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(final Event event) {
                if (event.type == SWT.KeyDown) {
                    System.out.println("key pressed ..........close shell");
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Is there any mistake here ??

Comment: Just listening to an event doesn't change what other listeners do.

Comment: What can I be doing here in order to invoke my listener instead of shell listener??

Comment: You could try calling `getListeners(SWT.KeyDown)` and then removing the listeners.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
event.doit = false;
```

that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the **ToolTip** class (it is the very base class of ColumnViewerToolTipSupport) you can see that there is no option to change the handling of events. It uses a private Listener implementation which listens to keydown (even not only to ESC) and other events.

The only API they provided is *afterHideToolTip(Event event)* where you can check for the ESC key of the event. But you can do only additonal stuff. There is no beforeHideToolTip for decision what you like to do with the tooltip event.

To your question why adding a Listener does not help: They are just added. The other listeners are also executed.